# Obtain the last index of item in an array or list that occur consecutively at least x times in the series

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a list

```
List<int> series = new List<int>()
{
    43, 41, 2, 3, 4, 52, 50, 51, 60, 5, 7, 9, 47, 45, 46
};

y = 40;
x = 3
```

I need to find each last item index in any series of items that exceeds `y` amount for `x` consecutive times.

Expected output will be 8 and 14:

```
{..52,50,51,60..} = 8 
{..47,45,46}  = 14
```

I want to get the position of `60`, because `60` is the *last* item in the group of *consecutive* values over `40`.

Here is what I have:

```
var occurrences = Enumerable.Range(0, series.Count - x + 1) 
.Where(i => Enumerable.Range(0, x).All(j => series[i + j] > y)) 
.Select(i => i + x - 1) 
.ToList();
```

I am getting 7,8,14, and what is required is only 8 & 14.

Comment: Do you have to use LINQ? This seems like one of these problems that would be easier with a simple for loop and counter.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not a case where you should use LINQ. But you can create an extension method for it which uses a loop under the hood and looks like LINQ from outside:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetLastIndexesWhere(this IList<int> list, Func<int, bool> where, int consecutiveCount = 1, int startIndex = 0)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int index = startIndex; index < list.Count; index++)
    {
        if (where(list[index])
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (count >= consecutiveCount)
                yield return index - 1;
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    if (count >= consecutiveCount)
    {
        yield return list.Count - 1;
    }
}
```

Your sample:

```
List<int> series = new List<int>()
{
    43, 41, 2, 3, 4, 52, 50, 51, 60, 5, 7, 9, 47, 45, 46
};

var allIndexes = series.GetLastIndexesWhere(i => i > 40, 3).ToList(); // 8 and 14
```

It's pretty efficient because it's only enumerated once, so the complexity is O(n).
Since it's an extension for `IList<int>` this works for arrays and lists as desired.

If you only want the first index you can use:

```
int index = series.GetLastIndexesWhere(i => i > 100, 3).FirstOrDefault(-1);
```

In this case the method exits before enumerating the whole list if there was one matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list of integers in reverse and check which numbers are greater than the specified limit and are consecutive and keep track of the count then add them to a List of integers and return them to the calling function like in the code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> series = new List<int>()
        {
            43, 41, 2, 3, 4, 52, 50, 51, 60, 5, 7, 9, 47, 45, 46
        };

        int y = 40;
        int x = 3;

        List<int> resultIndices = FindLastIndicesExceedingThreshold(series, y, x);
        
        foreach (int index in resultIndices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Index: " + index);
        }
    }

    static List<int> FindLastIndicesExceedingThreshold(List<int> series, int Y, int x)
    {
        List<int> resultIndices = new List<int>();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = series.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (series[i] > Y)
            {
                count++;
                if (count == x)
                {
                    resultIndices.Add(i);
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        resultIndices.Reverse();
        return resultIndices;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where a nice partitioning extension method can make a final query easy to write and quite powerful.

```
public static IEnumerable<(P Partition, V[] Values)> Partition<P, V>(this IEnumerable<V> source, Func<V, P> projection)
{
    var ve = source.GetEnumerator();
    if (ve.MoveNext())
    {
        var p = projection(ve.Current);
        var values = new List<V>();
        values.Add(ve.Current);
        while (ve.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!p.Equals(projection(ve.Current)))
            {
                yield return (p, values.ToArray());
                p = projection(ve.Current);
                values = new List<V>();
            }
            values.Add(ve.Current);
        }
        if (values.Any())
        {
            yield return (p, values.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

The key point here is that this is a general purpose method that could be used for many operations involving partitions.

Now I can write this:

```
List<int> series = new List<int>()
{
    43, 41, 2, 3, 4, 52, 50, 51, 60, 5, 7, 9, 47, 45, 46
};

int y = 40;
int x = 3;

var paritionsWithIndex =
    series
        .Select((Value, Index) => (Value, Index))
        .Partition(s => s.Value >= y);
```

That effectively gives me:

```
True: (43, 0), (41, 1)
False: (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)
True: (52, 5), (50, 6), (51, 7), (60, 8)
False: (5, 9), (7, 10), (9, 11)
True: (47, 12), (45, 13), (46, 14)
```

Now's it's easy to query that:

```
var query =
    from p in paritionsWithIndex
    where p.Partition
    where p.Values.Length >= x
    select p.Values.Last().Index;
```

That gives me `8` & `14` as expected.